# C: convert int[ ] to string

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Technically I realize they are slightly different as the array is null terminated. But looking for a way to convert

```
int charArray[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};  //ascii chars = ints
```

to

```
char *string;
```

Comment: Use `{ }` not `[ ]` for array values.

Comment: After posting my answer, now I really doubted that your `int` is a typo. After all, the variable has a name `charArray`.

Comment: Yu, dealing with ASCII chars here, so underlying ints...

Comment: but need to pass it in to another function as a string, aka char *

Comment: @Live2Enjoy7 I still don't get why you have an `int[]`, where does this data come from?

Comment: ASCII values don't relate to int. using char[] would be much easier to convert to string

Comment: @rmartinjak I have an array of ascii chars, which has to be in ascii because math is performed on them. But then I need to pass that array as a char * to another function. so that's where I was running into an issue

Comment: @Live2Enjoy7 `char` is an integer type and its range is guaranteed to be big enough to hold all ASCII values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `charArray` is not a string, you can't use the standard functions like `strcpy()`, or `strlen()`. Instead, copy every character, and add `'\0'` at the end. `sizeof(charArray) / sizeof(int)` can tell you how many characters to copy.

```
size_t sz = sizeof(charArray) / sizeof(int);
char *string = malloc(sz + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    string[i] = charArray[i];
}
string[sz] = '\0';
```

Comment: hmm if I want to factor this out into a function, how would you suggest I pass in the charArray[i]?

Comment: @Live2Enjoy7 Be careful when you pass the array as function argument, because it would be converted to a pointer, thus `sizeof` would give the size of a pointer instead of an array. You could consider passing the size of the array as another argument, something like `func(int array[], size_t size)`

Comment: unfortunately compiler is complaining for  string[i]=charArray[i] saying expected expression

Comment: this removes the warning string[i]=*charArray[i]

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert between `int[]` and `char *` in `c`. You can iterate over the array and build a `char*` with the desired value, though, then add `\0` to the end. You can also typecast, by using `(char*) charArray`, but this is prone to lots of problems, like the missing `\0` terminator. It won't work for `strcpy`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
char arr[] = {'h','e','l'};
string str(arr);
cout<<str<<endl; // output hel
```

Comment: he's probably asking C Code only

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen the tag.

Answer (score 0):

`charArray` is of type `int[8]` where as `string` is of type `char *`. They are different and incompatible types and you can't convert one into the other. What you can do is define an array of characters of enough size and then copy the integers(implicitly converted to `char` type) from the `charArray` into it.

```
// length of charArray

int length = sizeof charArray / sizeof charArray[0];

char string[length + 1]; // +1 for the null byte
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    string[i] = charArray[i];  // copy the characters 
string[i] = '\0';   // add the terminating null byte
```